# How to find and replace in 2 txt files with Python

Tags: python

i would like to search and replace Ids in two different txt files.

So i have those .txt files.

*OLDIDS.txt* which seems like:

```
12F
130
132
106
100
...
```

and the other file *MASTERIDS.txt* where the old and new Ids where splittet in columns like: (LEFT old ids, RIGHT new ids)

```
100    132
12F    1FF
106    256
...    ...
```

What I want to do is to open *OLDIDS.txt* like

```
f2 = open('OLDIDS.txt', 'w')
```

and search for the first id in the first line (which is `12F`) find this in the second line of *MASTERIDS.txt* and write the new ID `1FF` to the second line of *newFile.txt*.

Comment: What is the question and what have you tried?

Comment: Show us expected/end result.

Comment: expected result is a new.txt file where i can see this:

1FF
NONE
NONE
256
132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am converting the data in your MASTERIDS.txt to a dictionary. Key is the old id and value is the new ID. Then search for the dict for the new id using the value from OLDIDS.txt

**Demo:**

```
with open("PATH_TO_OLDIDS.txt", "r") as src:
    data = src.readlines()

d ={}
with open("PATH_TO_MASTERIDS.txt", "r") as toReplaceSRC:
    for i in toReplaceSRC.readlines():
        val = i.split()
        d[val[0].strip()] = val[1].strip()


for i in data:
toReplace = d.get(i.strip(), None)
if toReplace:
    print(i.strip(), " = ", toReplace)
```

**Output**:

```
12F  =  1FF
106  =  256
100  =  132
```